# Loader not being called when screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I facing a bit of trouble when using `AsyncTaskLoader` and the screen orientation changes. Let me give you some context on how my app is structured: I have a very simple app which fetches results from a url and displays it. The app consists of one `FragmentActivity` and three `Fragments`. My three fragment are as follows:

- First fragment is an edittext and a button to submit input.
- Second fragment shows a loading spinner
- Third fragment replaces the loading-fragment when the data is fetched to show the results.

The `AsyncTaskLoader` is used to load data from either a content provider (if it is cached) or from the network.

Everything works great until the screen oreintaion changes! I looked at the output of `LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true)`  and it seems the source of the problem is that `LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished` doesn't get called in my activity.

Here is a piece of the code that launches the loader:

```
/* This function is defined in the "first" fragment in an interface and
 * implemented in the activity */ 
@Override
public void onFormSubmission(String word) {                     

    showLoadingFragment();

    if ( mWord == null || mWord.equals(word) ) {
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, word, this);
    } else {
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, word, this);
    }

    // Store the word
    mWord = word;
}
```

The code that displays the result:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Bundle> loader, Bundle data) {
    // Validation and other stuff

      ResultFragment fragment = new ResultFragment();

      // Add the fragment to the 'result_fragment_container' FrameLayout
      getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
            // Replace loading fragment with the result
            .replace(R.id.result_fragment_container, fragment)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss(); 
}
```

Approaches I tried but failed:

- Setting `setRetaininstance(true)` in fragments.
- Setting `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"` in the manifest.

I'm out of ideas, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should avoid committing `FragmentTransaction`s inside `onLoadFinished()`... it's bad for the user experience. See my [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) about this topic for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` in the `onActivityCreated`  method. The initLoader will create or reconnect with a loader if it already exists

Answer (score 1):

Hi I can suggest 2 possible solutions:

**1)** From your question I'm not entirely sure what process your performing which is never calling OnLoadFinished() in the AsyncTask. I'll assume is a `Async` DB call or Web server call etc?

Regardless the onLoadFinished() probably doesn't get called because your Activity is Destroyed on rotation. you need to save the state you updated before rotation and `onDestroy()` is called

You can try keep a class variable status flag. This is set in your "update" `Async` task which flags whether your `Async` task is still running ie "updating" or not.

So:

- `bUpdating = true` when your update `async` task starts. Ie within
  `onPreExecute()`
- `bUpdating = false` when its finished. Ie within
  `onPostExecute()`

Then when  `onDestroy()` is called (always called before the screen rotate) you could check `bUpdating`. `IF` `TRUE` then you could save all details on screen, which would have been saved in the `Async` task, to `SharePreferences`

Within `onResume()` check your specific `SharePreferences` variables and if they exist then kickoff the `Async` update again.

So in short this will:

- save details to `SharedPreferences` **BEFORE** screen rotation - `onDestroy()` - if boolean says Async task running.
- `onResume()` **AFTER** screen rotation check `SharedPreferences` and save details via `Async`.
- Following this you should be guaranteed that your `onLoadFinished()` method is called.

There is probably a more reliable way also to check for Screen Rotation, i haven't done much with it.

**2)** Of course another alternative is to actually block screen rotation entirely on your particular Activity (because really, do you NEED rotation on that screen?).

I have an application which records video in background and uploads 10second segments. It was causing large headaches with screen rotation and my Async tasks, so I blocked rotation entirely as it was completely unnecessary. Here is code for the AndroidManifest.xml file to lock Screen orientation as Portrait:

```
     <activity 
        android:name="com.blah.YourActivity"
        android:label="Register"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

I hope that can help you out

**Edit:** Also, could be better more categorical ways to know that screen is rotating:

ie this sort of code:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
    }
}
```

Example taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186767/android-screen-rotation-on-destroy-and-services-connundrum)

you could just put your `SharePreferences` save in there. but onResume() will still be used to grab your details back from.

Also a [link to `SharePreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) incase you've not used it before

**Edit2!:** One other thing. I just re-read your question, and you mention "Loader" for some reason i had it in my head this was saving data, not loading. Have you tried simply re-calling `AsyncTaskLoader()` when onResume() is called?? If your not saving then you can ignore everything i said about retaining your data to `SharePreferences` because you can just kickoff the load Async task again at onResume() (which runs after Rotation)