# Android BluetoothChat example: bluetooth connection lost upon screen rotation

Tags: android, bluetooth, screen-orientation

I have just imported Android's BluetoothChat example into Eclipse. In the Android manifest, I can see that the option `android:configChanges="orientation"` was already there. However, when I tested the app on two real phones, the connection was always lost whenever I rotated the screen.

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186767/android-screen-rotation-on-destroy-and-services-connundrum), a user reported that the connection was not lost when the `android:configChanges="orientation"` option was there, but this is not what I have experienced.

The only modification I have made to the code is to add the line

> getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

right after `super.onCreate()` in the `onCreate()` method. This change was made [to fix a null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418802/bluetoothchat-example-nullpointerexception) and I don't think it has anything to do with the screen rotation problem. Does anyone know what is the cause of lost connections and how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this one? Should be able to do the trick.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screensize"
```

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
> also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
> declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
> must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
> value. That is, you must decalare
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html